# Accessing strings element addresses

Tags: c++, string, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void reverse(char *m) {
}

int main() {
    string m="";
    reverse(m);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code when i try to access the string through a character pointer the compiler gives the following error

> ```
> -  cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'void reversewords(char*)'
> ```

Can anyone please tell me the reason behind it ?? Also please let me know the way i can access the string through a pointer.

Comment: Just as a side note: If you use `std::string` you should `#include <string>` instead of relying on `#include<iostream>` doing so. Also drop that misbehavior of `using namepace std;` please. Use the namespace scope `std::` either explicitly, or in a more specific manner like `using std::string;`

Comment: You could change the signature of your function to use `const std::string&` and remove some of these issues.

Answer (score 4):

`std::string` and `char*` are distinct type and are not interchangeable. There are some implicit conversions implemented for `std::string` that allows for `char*` to be converted to `std::string` but the opposite is not true.

Since C++17 you can use [`std::string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) to get a non-const pointer to the string's data. Since C++11 you can also safely take the address of the first character in a `std::string` and use it as pointer to a null terminated string. There does not seem to be a portable way of achieving this prior to C++11.

Prefer using `std::string` directly along with standard container algorithms rather than using functions designed for c strings. The usual way of reversing a `std::string` is to use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello, World!";
    std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    std::cout << str << std::endl; // Prints "!dlroW ,olleH"
}
```

Comment: The `std::string::data()` reference mentions "since C++17" concerning the non-const pointer. Anyway, +1

Comment: @StephanLechner I had not noticed that. I will add it to my answer. My mention of C++11 was regarding the null termination of the data.

Comment: Prior to C++17, you can use `operator&` with `std::string::operator[]` to get a non-const pointer to the data. Just note the data is not guaranteed to be contiguous in memory (or null-terminated) until C++11 (though most implementations are, to simplify `c_str()` implementations).